# QMimeData: How to properly copy formatted text to clipboard?

Tags: qt, clipboard

In my application I want the option to copy text as formatted string to clipboard, with parts in italic and other parts in bold, to be pasted later to MS Word or Google Doc. I have the following code:

```
QString str = "A text with <i>italic</i> and <b>bold</b> words."
QClipboard *clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
QMimeData *rich_text = new QMimeData;
rich_text->setHtml(str);
clipboard->setMimeData(rich_text);
```

Everything works fine - when I later paste from clipboard to MS Word, I have formatted text. But if I paste to Google Doc, nothing happens (nothing is being pasted at all). Also, if I paste into simple text editor (say, Notepad), nothings is being pasted as well. I would expect in this case to be pasted only plain text without html tags - e.g., if I select and copy rich text in MS Word and paste into text editor, I get plain text, without any formatting information. How can I do that in Qt?